# That was the time I knew I should "come/go" back home. - I am at home saying this; which to use?

Tags: usage

The scenario is this:
I am saying this at my home to my friend but when I thought about that, I was at a bar.

**Example 1**

> That was the time I knew I should **go** back home.

**Example 2**

> That was the time I knew I should **come** back home.

Comment: Either works, for the reasons described below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I’d rather come or go with you](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/336980/i-d-rather-come-or-go-with-you)

Comment: Please note: I received five downvotes which are all mistaken. Please read it carefully. If you are at home when you say it, I would use: come back home. [spoken at home to a friend who is present: "What did you think John?" Answer: "I thought I should come back here, come home."

Comment: On a separate issue, *That was when I knew ...*    would refer to a moment whereas *That was the time I knew ...* would refer to an occasion.

Comment: There's not enough context to decide between **go** and **come**.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 'go', since the speaker is talking about what he knew ***then***, when he ***wasn't*** at home.

It's basically the same principle as the ["backshifting"](https://preply.com/en/question/what-is-the-backshifting-rule-in-reported-speech-70735) in *He told me what his name **was***, which we do because the containing utterance establishes the ***temporal*** "frame of reference" as being in the past.

By the same token, in OP's example, the ***locative*** frame of reference (at the time) was the bar, not "home". Standard use of ***come / go home*** is governed by the current frame of reference, which in this context comes from the utterance itself, not the speaker<sup>1</sup>.

---

Here's [a relevant usage example](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22should%20go%20home%20so%20here%20i%20am%22) from Google Books...

> *...I remembered that the voices said I should **go home**. So **here** I am.*

Here are [several more examples](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to%20go%20home%20so%20here%20I%22) (interleaved with some irrelevant text matches).

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that a homesick person says *I want to **go** home* when talking to someone else - unless the person he's talking to is ***at*** the speaker's home (on the telephone, for example), in which case the homesick person says *I want to **come** home*. I point this out to show that it's not necessarily the *speaker's* location that counts.

[**Come or go? (Cambridge Dictionary)**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/come-or-go)

Comment: I agree with this answer.  **Go** sounds much more natural, for the reasons you describe.

Comment: I wasn't *quite* being honest with my first sentence above. If Michael's (now deleted) answer hadn't already been posted I'd have probably just said ***both versions are fine - it depends how you look at it***. (The whole point of me "mirroring" Michael's answer was to give that implication in a way that I thought might be mildly amusing, but it seems to have fallen a bit flat! :)

Comment: ...Although speaker is ***at*** home, it could make a world of difference if he's ***on the phone*** talking to his friend (as opposed to the friend being there in person, having come to visit his homecoming mate! :)

Comment: [spoken at John's home to a friend who is present:] "What did you think John?" Answer: "I thought I should come back here, come home."