"Will" vs "be going" to talk about something that is planned
Context: Yesterday, I decided to visit Uncle Peter next month. This means the decision was made before speaking. Now, I want to inform my friend about this visit. I want to invite my friend to join with me.
(1)I am going to visit Uncle Peter next month. Would you like to go with me?
(2)I am visiting Uncle Peter next month. Would you like to go with me?
(3)I will visit Uncle Peter next month. Would you like to go with me?
(4)I will be visiting Uncle Peter next month. Would you like to go with me?
I think that all 4 sentences works for this context. Right?
I was taught that simple future "will" is only used for a decision right at the time of speaking. But this context refers to a decision before the time of speaking. Does (3) with simple future "wil" sound natural here?

Your 1, 2, and 4 are fine. Number 3 sounds a bit off to this American’s ear.
As a side note, many speakers would replace go with me in all 4 of your examples by come with me, since for them, go involves movement away from the speaker, whereas come involves movement towards—or along with—the speaker. So yes, for them it’s perfectly correct to say, “I’m going. Want to come?”

Re come and go, this might amuse you: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/336980/i-d-rather-come-or-go-with-you/337002#337002 I got six downvotes, one from someone who should know better. Specifically, look at the one involving the office. Unbelievable that six dvs could be so wrong. That's why I gave you a +1.

According to your context, you have already decided to visit your uncle.

(1) In this context, you could use "I am going to visit"

(2) If you have already planned and managed to do so, you can use "I am visiting"

(4) is quite formal - used when something is already planned. 

(3) You have just decided to visit your uncle and you declare it, you could say "I will visit..."


Edit: "You can also refer English Grammar in Use 5th ed"

There isn't so much of a difference between "will" and "am going to"; the bigger difference is in the inclusion of the auxiliary verb "be" in either.
"I will visit" implies a plan to visit at some point in the future, whereas "I will be visiting" suggests a more specific timeframe or ongoing action, indicating that the visit will occur during a particular period or as part of a schedule. When you add in a timeframe like "next month" then it becomes a plan to visit some time during that month and a plan to visit at a specific time in that month respectively.

Does the sentence (3) with simple future “will” sound natural in this context?

Does it sound off in this context?
