I am going to Berlin next month/ I will go to Berlin next month


We can use either will or be going to to talk about something that is planned, or something that we think is likely to happen in the future:

We will study climate change in a later part of the course. (or We are going to study…)
Where will you stay in Berlin? (or Where are you going to stay…?)
The south of the city won't be affected by the power cuts. (or …isn't going to be affected…)


Let's look at the highlighted lines in my grammar book.
I will create a context like this:

A:(1) I am going to Berlin next month.
B:(2) Where will you stay in Berlin?
A:(3) I will stay in a small hotel.

In this context, If I use simple future "will" in (1) I will go to Berlin next month. It seems that the sentence will sound odd.
But why does it sounds natural in (2) with the simple future "will"?
According to this AmEng user the sentence “I will visit Uncle Peter next month” doesn't sound natural but I don't understand why.

Does this answer your question? "When I grow up, I am going to be a doctor"- Is it correct? Also ''will'' or ''going to'' and others.

I have read all related threads, but I am still not sure with this context.

I will created?? Why does it sound natural to use x. Why does x verb. What does x verb, Why do x verb. How, what, why, when, where x verb.

@Lambie, Thank you, I just corrected my mistakes that you advised.

Your grammar book explains this will/going to. :)

@Lambie, but when I ask natives, in this context , the sentence " I will go to Berlin" doesn't sound good to inform my plan to go to Berlin. They says the version " I am going to Berlin" sounds good.

@LEHANH I don’t think so, which native say that to you? Both of them are commonly used.

That's right. They are both commonly used. going to is more definite, that's all.

@Lambie If I already have plan to go to Berlin before speaking. All things for this trip have beeen arranged. Can I use "I will go to Berlin next month."?

Yes, three people have said ok.  Maybe it's time for you to google it and read the links in the first comment.

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/352021/will-vs-be-going-to-talk-about-something-that-is-planned/352324#352324
This thread has the same example. Paul Tanenbaum's answer says that the sentence with simple future "will "sounds off for a plan decided. That is why I am still in doubt.

@Lambie please read the answer on the link I gave above. Could you please explain why some people say that "will" sound off, but some people is happy to use "will" in this context.

A downvote on a question that shows effort, research (see textbook image and link to a previous question) and careful thought. Yet, this question is downvoted. Daft, totally daft.

"I am going to Berlin next month" and "I will go to Berlin next month." are both fine, even "I will be going to Berlin next month" is fine.
This one is purely a matter of preference. If there is any actual difference in their meanings it is too subtle for me (AME speaker) to pick up on.

If I already have plan to go to Berlin before speaking. All things for this trip have beeen arranged. Can I use  "I will go to Berlin next month."?

In American English, when speaking in an informal conversation about one's plans to visit a person and/or place, we normally do so like this:

I'm going to visit my uncle next month.
-- Will you be staying with him?
No. My cousin, who has two small children, is visiting at the same time and she and the children will be staying in my uncle's guest bedroom. I'll be staying at a hotel nearby.

Notice the contracted forms, "I'm" and "I'll" in the statements and the uncontracted form in the question: "will you be staying...".  But the questioner could also ask it this way: "You'll be staying with him?"  The phrasing looks like a statement but the intonation when spoken will turn it into a question.
We can also say "I plan to stay" or "I'm staying" as variants in the same informal register.


A: (1) I am going to [go to] Berlin next month.

Technically, this is not the be going to form but the Present Continuous.
When the main verb is go, speakers will often omit the go to. Both forms are perfectly appropriate for a future event that has been planned or organised at some point in the past.

A: I will go to Berlin next month.

This sentence is grammatical. It could suggest that the speaker made the decision to go to Berlin at the moment of speaking or it could be stating a fact (see an example at the end of this post). If the decision to go to Berlin was made in the past, and arrangements have been made; e.g. booking a plane ticket and a hotel room, the  be going to or the Present Continuous is preferable. For example, A: “I'm going to stay at a hotel” or  “I'm staying at a hotel”.

B: (2) Where will you stay in Berlin?

As a response to A (1) this is appropriate, we assume that speaker B is hearing the news for the first time. Using will in this situation is acceptable but I’d argue that native speakers will echo their interlocutor and use the same form, this is called parallel construction.

A: I am going to Berlin next month.
B: Where are you staying?  (also: Where are you going to stay?)

Similarly, A's response using will matches B's (2) earlier question, “Where will you stay?”

A:(3) I will stay in a small hotel.

Personally, I wouldn't use will for a planned trip. I would  use either the Present Continuous form or be going to.
  A: I'm going to Berlin next month.
  B: Where are you staying?
  A: I'm staying at a small hotel.
    —OR—
  A: I'm going to [go to] Berlin next month.
  B: Where are you going to stay?
  A: I'm going to stay at a small hotel.
A little self-plugging: for using "be going to" and the Present Continuous to speak about the future, see my answers here and here.
For “will" versus “going to” see this EL&U question: When do I have to use 'will' instead of 'going to'?
In the Ngram chart below, during the period 1900-2019 (circa), we see that "leaving next month", compared to "going to leave…" and "will leave…", is the most frequent form since the mid-1970s.

Examples of usage taken from Google Books


I've arranged to be transferred to California. We're going to leave next month. Remember, you must not tell your mother.”
The Art Fair (2014) by David Lipsky
‘When do they leave us? asked John. I do hope they won't go for a long time. i love the swallows and the martins.’
‘They will go in September and October,’ said Uncle Merry, ‘but the swifts will leave next month. Some of the old cuckoos will leave us this month, towards the end.’
Summer Holiday Stories (1950) by Enid Blyton


The phrase ‘will leave next month’ is stating a fact that swifts migrate from the UK to the south between July and August.


‘Aye well, I'm on my way down to Tyrone. We're going to be living on a farm there.’
Mr and Mrs Jackson looked at one another warily. Yes, Sadie was a sore trial, and only last night Tommy had told them he was leaving next month for Australia.
‘Tyrone,’ said Mrs Jackson, as it it were the moon. ‘What're you going there for?’
’Kevein's mother comes from there. We're going to be living next door to her, and his sister, and brother-in-law, and seven or eight other brothers and sisters,’ Sadie added, unable to resist watching their reaction.
Into Exile (1973) by Joan Lingard



"I will go to Berlin next month."
When hearing this sentence the listener have the feeling that I just made the decision to Berlin right at the time speaking. But It is just that the FEELING. Right?  When hearing that sentence, the listener actually don't know if I have book flight, hotels or not.

I will go to Berlin next month Being familiar with nonnative speakers and how they express themselves,  I might guess the arrangements have already  been made, I'd probably ask: "Have you booked the flight?”  If the answer is "yes" that tells me they have made the necessary arrangements. If they reply: "Not yet" it means they haven't got round to it.  If the speaker is an English-speaking person I might think they are expressing a desire or a need  but nothing has been formally organised yet.

Love to know what the downvote is for. Anyone?

when a native speaker has things arranged ( buying ticket/ booking hotel), they don't use " I will go to Berlin next month" version to inform other about their trip. Right?

Are there any chance a native speaker would use " I will go to Berlin next month" version when things for the trip have been arranged?

As Lambie said above, this sentence also is commonly used when we already have plan for the trip. I am so confused

I'm definitely going to Paris, but I will not go to Berlin. It's called will of intention. It has zero do with what you have planned.

@LEHANH Are there any chance a native speaker would use " I will go to Berlin next month" version when things for the trip have been arranged? People will understand what you are saying, all three  constructions: "I'm going [to go] next month" and "I will go to X next month" are all grammatical.

@Lambie I will go to Berlin next month  can express intention, it can also express a need  and you can't rule out the possibility of it being an instant decision either.  Your example of "I will not go to Berlin" is not identical to the OP's short dialogue, "I/he/she/ etc won't do something" is often a rebuke, a refusal to do that thing. That shows a stronger intention of NOT doing something. Anyways, thanks for the comment.

In any case isn't any decision an expression of going to / will intention?

@LEHANH As Lambie said above, this sentence also is commonly used when we already have plan for the trip   Lambie actually said: That's right. They are both commonly used. going to is more definite, that's all What does "going to is more definite" mean to you?

@LEHANH  SamBC's answer in FumbleFingers' second link focuses on prediction e.g. Italy is going to have a hot summer" vs "Italy will have a hot summer" They both mean the same, they're both predictions about the temperature of the weather in summer   but when we add I think Italy … it adds a note of uncertainty. Your question is not about certainty or something that is likely to happen at some point  in the future. Ergo, your question is not a duplicate.

@LEHANH there is an older question which asks about the differences between "going to" and "will" for predictions and future plans In-depth explanation of the difference between "will" and "going to"? The top answer by tunny is very well-written and quite thorough. Try to understand that to go through each and every situation and explain all the possible nuances would require pages. People like short to the point answers or ones that go into incredible depth, but the former often earn more upvotes than the latter. Hope this helped you.

@Mari-LouA I have read a lot of related thread on this forum, but I haven't found the definite answer, so I decided to create a new thread here. I know that there are so many situations, we can use "be going to" "present continuous" and "will+bare infinitive" interchangeably without any difference.

But on this thread, I only would like to know about this context, in which I already had plan, and had some arrangements for the trip. Now I meet my friend, and I want to inform about this trip.
The question is: when my friend hear "I will go to Berlin next week", does she knows that I already decided to go to Berlin before come to meet her to inform about the trip.

Yes, your friend will understand that next week you are going to Berlin. You can even use the present simple if you like "I go to Berlin next week” that is stating a fact, which the speaker has little control over. But why are you insisting so much on this "will" form? No one is saying it is "wrong" to use that construction. No one. I only stated using Pres. Cont and "be going to" would be my personal preference. By the way, is there's something you're not telling us?

With Pres. Cont and "be going to", the listener will understand that I had some arrangements such as booking fly, hotel. But with the "will" form, does the listener understand the same?

@LEHANH  Sorry but I am not going to continue this cross examination any longer. We keep going in circles. I said everything that I know from experience and learnt from grammar books. I wish you luck with your studies (By the way in several comments you made a number of simple grammar errors. Perhaps you should focus more on those instead?)

e.g ...when my friend hears "I will go to Berlin next week", does she know that....

Thanks so much for your supports.

@LE123 Did you just change your name?? We've worked hard to help you but you seem to always belabor the ideas, repeating the same thing again.

@Lambie, Yes I just change the name. I kept repeating the same thing because I haven't understood.

Yes, I just changed the name. Read this transcript from the BBC or better yet, listen to it: https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/intermediate/unit-17/session-2/activity-3 [support is uncountable, unless its a physical thing]

Please take any further discussion to the OP. There are already too many comments here! Thank you.
