Simple future vs other future tenses when talking about a plan

A: Do you have plans tonight?
B: Yes,
(1) I will watch a movie on Netflix with my friend tonight. Would
you like to join?
(2) I am going to watch a movie on Netflix with my friend tonight.
Would you like to join?
(3) I am watching a movie on Netflix with my friend tonight. Would
you like to join?
(4) I will be watching a movie on Netflix with my friend tonight.
Would you like to join?

To me, I think that  all 4 versions are correct to use.
I have asked a lot of native speakers, some says that (1) with simple future will sound off to talk about a decided plan, but some other native says that still natural to use (1) in this context about a fixed plan.
I posted a similar question on the below link:
sounds a bit off to this American’s ear.=> in this link an native speaker says that simple future-will sound off.
There isn't so much of a difference=> in this link another native speaker says that simple future is like other ways talking about the future.
So finally, in conclusion, I would like to know if it sounds off or unnatural when using the future simple-will to talk about a decided plan.
Why is there difference in the opinion between natives in the use of simple future-will for a decided plan?

(1) is technically correct, but in real life most people would use one of the other forms. (I don't quite understand your first paragraph; it seems to say that both groups agreed that (1) isn't natural.)

@KateBunting thank you for your comment and I just corrected my first paragraph

@KateBunting does the version (1) sound off to you?

I don't know anyone who would say 'would you like to join?'. Maybe join us or come too or watch it too.

When I said 'most people would use one of the other forms', I meant to imply 'because (1) isn't natural'. (And I agree with Michael about join - I was concentrating on the first sentence.)

The contracted forms will always sound more natural in speech:

I'll watch a movie on Netflix with my friend tonight. Would you like /care to join us?
I'll be watching a movie…,
I'm going to watch a movie…,
I'm watching a movie…"

To this user, they each mean the same thing but there is a subtle  difference, which is determined by the time of speaking, in other words when these phrases are uttered.

You decide at that specific moment you want to stay in and watch a movie.

In reality, this is the least likely version because it includes a previous arrangement, i.e. you have already invited one friend to come over.

You are telling someone what you are doing at a specific point in the future.
and 4. are interchangeable, there is no difference in meaning. But many authors of grammar books will argue that 3. also expresses an intention while 4. expresses something that has been planned/arranged.


See also an old answer of mine

In reality, this is the least likely version=> if I used the version (1), would it sound wrong or unnatural in this context?

No. The point is (as so often happens) that all the sentences can be natural and correct given the right circumstances. But some circumstances are more or less likely to happen in real life.

@PeterKirkpatrick, I only want to know if the sentence with simple future sound wrong in this context

@LE123 Why wouldn't you prefer to sound more natural? 2-4 are not a problem. 1.  is not as good because you have previously invited a friend  but yes, there's no law saying you cannot use will, and like I said all 4 versions have  the same meaning but 1. is a bit problematic for the reason I gave. Why don't you believe me or other users?

And I've tried to give you my answer. It depends on the context. @Mari-LouA has given an example of when it would be the right thing to say. Other times it would be wrong. Don't just think about what is right or wrong. Think also about what it means.

+1 I would just add: I'll be watching a movie on Netflix with my friend tonight so please don't come over until it finishes. [for example]

I have another context: A: I am going to visit Paris next week. B: Where 'll you stay?. A: I'll stay in a small hotel.
Does the simple future in "Where 'll you stay?" and  "I'll stay in a small hotel" also sound unnatural?

@LE123 If you can say "I'll watch a movie tonight, why wouldn't you be able to say: I'll stay at a small hotel? Anyway, there are tons of answers about this on this site. It was just suggested to you, to use contractions. That's how we speak unless there is a reason not to.

I know that I can use simple future, but I wan to know if it sounds natural or not in "Where 'll you stay?" and "I'll stay in a small hotel"

@LE123  Can you please explain why my answer does not satisfy you? If you believe  that the Pure Future (will) is as natural-sounding as the other three constructions, in that specific situation, you should explain why. You wrote a new question asking about the same thing, the only difference being the topic (Paris).  In your research, can you cite a reference (not someone's opinion) which says "will" can also be used to talk about a plan or decision that was made in the past?

Let see the picture I post in this link. Because my grammar book cites this sentence   "Where 'll you stay?" in the use of the future simple, this is a reliable grammar book, so I think this sentence must be natural enough to use. This sentence is talking about a decided plan, staying is a decided plan, so from what I learned from you, I think that this sentence is unnatural to use. The natural ways to use is "Where are you going to stay" and " Where are you staying".  If so, why does my grammar book use an unnatural sentence as an example? @Mari-LouA See the link below.

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/352288/i-am-going-to-berlin-next-month-i-will-go-to-berlin-next-month

The book actually says "Where'll you stay?" in response to "I'm going to visit Paris next month."? There's nothing wrong about asking "Where will you stay?"  when the news is fresh off the press, the speaker is reacting spontaneously to their friend's statement.  But if the person going on holiday had replied "I'll stay at a friend's house" I'd say a more natural response would be to use the Present Continuous: "I'm staying at a friend's"

@LE123  Person A tells B they are going to Paris. Person B does not know where, so they ask "Where will you stay?" This is acceptable, because Person B is not the one going on holiday, they didn't plan anything. Person A replies: "I'm (going to  stay) staying at a friend's". If Person A has not yet decided, or booked anything they might respond "I haven't decided yet" or "I'm not sure, maybe I'll book an AirBnB"

@Mari-LouA The book actually says "Where'll you stay?" in response to "I'm going to visit Paris next month."?=> No, the book doesn't say that, but I think this question must be in response to something like "I'm going to visit Paris next month."

@Mari-LouA In this article, the writer stated that if the verb is be, we can use "Pure Future" (will) to talk about something planned before speaking. What do you think?

@AnIELTSLearner  Is  that connected to the OP's question here? Look at the examples, there is no "Tomorrow I will be at [location].The article also ends with ... when we have a plan or intention to do something in the future, we usually use other tenses or expressions, such as the present continuous or going to.

I understand that the OP's examples don't include be as the main verb, but it is related to whether we can use pure future to talk about planned schedules. I'm tutoring a kid whose grammar exercises include lots of questions asking us to choose between pure future and other tenses. I've always told him that he can't use pure future for a plan or intention, but now that I've read some conflicting information online, I just don't want to teach him something wrong.

@AnIELTSLearner the word "usually" should give you a clue :)
